# Radius of circle, restricted to Golden Rectangle, with area of half the Golden Ratio

Tags: geometry

- Let $R$ be the Golden Rectangle (sides of length 1 and $\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$)
- Centered at one of the vertices of $R$, inscribe a circle of radius $\lambda$
- What is the value of $\lambda$ that partitions $R$ into 2 equal halves by area?

[image]

- I was able to determine a function for the convex region, parameterized by $\lambda$; $C(\lambda)$ and from there, use software to find a meaningful root of $C(\lambda)-\frac{\phi}{2}$ ($\approx1.016144)$. However, I am disappointed I couldn't find an analytical solution.
- I am looking for an expression for $\lambda$

$Aside:$ I was somewhat expecting $\lambda$ to be more "interesting"

Comment: Because the problem is equivalent to solving a non-trivial equation that has a variable both inside and outside of a trig function, there is no analytic solution. Your numerical approximation (which I have confirmed) is as good at you're going to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterizing by $\theta$ as in the figure ...

[image]

... the goal is to solve ...

$$\frac12\cdot 1 \cdot \phi = X + Y = \frac12 \cdot 1 \cdot \tan\theta + \frac12 \cdot \sec^2\theta \cdot \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right) $$
$$\to\qquad 2\phi = 2\tan\theta + (\pi-2\theta)\sec^2\theta$$
$$\to\qquad(\pi-2\theta)\tan^2\theta+2\tan\theta + \pi-2\phi-2\theta = 0 \tag{$\star$}$$
Because $(\star)$ is a non-trivial [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), it *cannot* be solved algebraically. *Mathematica* gives this numerical approximation $\theta = 0.1784924382\ldots$ so that the radius of the circle is 
$$\lambda = \sec\theta = 1.0161440156726\ldots$$

Comment: Hey Blue. Thanks for the response. OK - the reference to a non-trivial transcendental equation was what I was afraid of, but thank you for confirming. Nice image too :)

Comment: @Kay: I'm glad to be of service. :) BTW: You mention in a comment to John that you accepted my answer ... Actually, you haven't. The up-arrow gives an up-vote, but the checkmark is for officially *accepting* the answer. Regards ...

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry! Thank you again :P

Answer (score 2):

As Blue answered, there is no analytical solution to the equation
$$(\pi-2\theta)\tan^2(\theta)+2\tan(\theta) + \pi-2\phi-2\theta = 0$$ and numerical methods are required.

However, we can make quite nice approximation of
$$f(\theta)=(\pi-2\theta)\tan^2(\theta)+2\tan(\theta) + \pi-2\phi-2\theta$$ using Padé approximants built around $\theta=0$ since the derivatives at this point are quite simple $\{0,2 \pi ,-8,16 \pi ,-128,272 \pi \}$.

For example, the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant would be
$$\frac{(\pi -2 \phi )+  \left(\frac{4}{3}-\frac{8 \phi }{3 \pi }\right)\theta +\frac{\left(12 \pi ^2 \phi -32 \phi +3 \pi ^3+16 \pi \right)}{9 \pi
   ^2}\theta
   ^2 }{1+\frac{4 }{3 \pi }\theta +\left(\frac{16}{9 \pi ^2}-\frac{2}{3}\right) \theta
   ^2}$$ and the solution of the quadratic equation in numerator evaluates as $\approx 0.178564$.

Notice that a simple Taylor expansion around $\theta=0$ is
$$f(\theta)=(\pi -2 \phi )+\pi  \theta ^2+O\left(\theta ^3\right)$$ leading to $$\theta \approx \sqrt{\frac{2 \phi }{\pi }-1}\approx 0.173414$$ form which Newton method converges extremely fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \theta_n \\
 0 & 0.17341404095680294715 \\
 1 & 0.17856358886001367599 \\
 2 & 0.17849245180567710065 \\
 3 & 0.17849243822881146264 \\
 4 & 0.17849243822881096809
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let  $f(x)=1, g(x)=\sqrt{\lambda^2-x^2}$

My approach was to find the area under curves using integration.

Let it be known that $\lambda>1$ because if $\lambda=1$, then the area of the divided regions of the rectangle would be: 
$$A_1=\frac\pi4;A_2=\phi-\frac\pi4$$ 
$$A_1\ne A_2$$

The area of the quarter circle can be written as:
$$\frac{A_\circ}4=\int_0^\lambda g(x)dx-\int_0^{\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}}g(x)-f(x)dx$$
Or as I was told, it could be written as:
$$\frac{A_\circ}4=\int_0^\lambda g(x)dx-\int_1^{\lambda}\sqrt{\lambda^2-y^2}dy$$

So far, this is the my best representation for finding $\lambda$:

$$\frac\phi2=\int_0^\lambda\sqrt{\lambda^2-x^2}dx-\int_1^{\lambda}\sqrt{\lambda^2-y^2}dy \tag{1}$$

Now, evaluating $(1)$:
$$\frac\phi2=\frac\pi4\lambda^2-\frac12(\lambda^2\sec^{-1}\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2-1})$$

Wolfram tells me $\lambda=1.01614$, which agrees with OP's answer, but I believe $\lambda$ above can solved algebraically.

Comment: Apologies, $R$ is actually the radius

Comment: Let me replace $R$ with $\lambda$

Comment: Thanks for the response! I chose Blue's answer, as the accepted, only because he mentioned the non-existence of an analytical solution, and his approach was similar to my own.